# Swift Variable used within its own initial value

Tags: ios, swift, initialization

I'm trying to initialize an object and I get this error: `Variable used within its own initial value`

Here is my code:

[image]

Why can't I do it like this?

Comment: Class names start with an uppercase letter. Instance names start with a lowercase letter. There is a reason for this. `public class Entry: NSObject`. Having said that, looking at Entry class it should probably be a struct.

Comment: Why you specify public explicitly everywhere ?

Comment: @Fogmeister, from memory consumption perspective, Entry should rather be a class (as that is of reference type) then a struct (as that is a value type and gonna be copied all the way around when new "var/let references" to it appear). Also, I guess that Entry is supposed to be a subclass of NSObject (for the sake of KVO usage or whatever else).

Comment: @ArthurGevorkyan I disagree. Memory consumption of this data is minimal to the point of being negligible. Using reference types can be more complex as you can get into situations where several parts of he app can be mutating data at the same time. It becomes harder to have a source of the "truth". With value type objects this isn't an issue and parts of the app that do need to mutate can be written with the intention of mutating and passing mutated data back etc... That way there is always one source of the truth.

Comment: @Fogmeister, as I said, it's all about memory consumption solely. I haven't been speaking about mutability at all. Your point of view is as good as mine, it just relates to a completely different aspect.

Comment: @ArthurGevorkyan yes, but like I replied... It isn't about memory at all. If you have 1000 events and they are reference type then you decide to edit one then you have 1000 events. If they are value type then you have 1001 events. Even then, the memory limits of the current devices would allow for holding tens of thousands of events in memory. They are so trivial that they take very little memory. The benefits of having value type data far out weighs the negligible memory usage decrease.

Comment: @ArthurGevorkyan there is a WWDC video that I can find a link for if you'd like. It explains it much better than I can in the comments. :-)

Comment: @Fogmeister, would be kind of you :)

Comment: @ArthurGevorkyan session 414: Building better apps with value types. From this years wwdc.

Comment: @Fogmeister, thanks for pointing that out. I will definitely watch that and reconsider our discussion.

Comment: @Fogmeister, alright, the video explains that a sctruct made out of strings shares the string fields among all the copies of an instance (behind the scenes) until it's referenced with a var and mutated. This is not obvious and is kind of intrinsic provided by the Swift runtime for variable-lenght value types. Thanks for the video once again, it helped a lot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The others answers are correct. I would like to add a few suggestions here because I see many very ugly things in you code :[

### 1. Type names should be UpperCamelCase

So name your class `Entity` instead of `entity`

### 2. Extending NSObject...

Why does `Entity` extend `NSObject`? Do you have a valid reason to do it?

### 3. Visibility

I see lots of `public` in you code. Why? Are you creating a library? Because probably there's no need to make `public` all that stuff.

### 4. Struct instead of Class

If `Entity` is simply a container for a bunch of data it should be a `struct`, not a `class`. You'll get better performance.

### 5. The "created" property declared as String? Seriously?

Too often I see code where the `String` type is used in place of many others types (such as `Int`, `NSDate`, `Bool`, ...). Why? This makes extremely difficult to deal with that value every time you need to perform some action/check strictly related the real type (like adding numbers, comparing dates, etc...)

### 6. Everything initialised to "", why?

What does it mean when `created` is an empty string? If you are using the empty `String` to indicate the absence of a value you should use `nil` instead (making of course the property an optional type).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Some answer to your points:
2 - I pass the object to an external library that only accept NSObject, not struct.
3 - Easy access to data in object, is it better to make get/set methods?
4 - same as 2
5 - I get Data from an API and sometimes i get "no time set" instead of a datetime for published for example.

Comment: **2)** Ok, then you are right **3)** If your remove `public` the property becomes `internal` then visibile to your entire project. This should be enough to access it. Anyway don't manually write getters/setters. **4)** When your API sends you `no time set`, just set the related property to `nil`: it's a better way to express no value then the text `no time set`.

Answer (score 5):

You can't give a variable the same name as a type: the compiler's getting confused and it thinks your reference to `entry` the type is referring to `entry` the new variable, hence the warning.

The best solution is to use CamelCase names for types and llamaCase names for variables, as recommended by Apple in "The Swift Programming Language". For example:

```
public var entry = Entry()
```

and

```
public class Entry: NSObject {
```

(Note also that you needn't explicitly state the type of the `entry` variable, as it's easily deduced from its value.)

Answer (score 2):

You just have a collision of the name of the entry variable reference and the entry class. Just rename the entry class: make it "Entry" for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Change the name of the instance because you can't use the same name as the class. In addition you should change the name of the class to uppercase where it becomes easier to differ class name and instance

```
var levelEntry = Entry()
```

Comment: IMHO, naming classes in a groovy way (upper camel case) is a better solution compared to making the other names deal with awkward class names :)